# Elephant.io + Socket.io return [object Object]

Tags: php, symfony, socket.io

I trying to make a realtime chat with Elephant.io (Elephantio bundle) and Socket.io on symfony2 app.

The connection between socket.io server and my symfony app is working well but when i trying to pass data to socket.io it return **[object Object]**.

I do this like that :

```
#Config.yml
nc_elephant_io:
    clients:
        default:
            connection: http://localhost:3006
            version: 1.x
        socketio_key:
            connection: http://localhost:3000
            version: 1.x
```

My controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $client = $this->get('elephantio_client.socketio_key');
    $elephantIOClient = $client->getElephantIO();

    $elephantIOClient->initialize();
    $elephantIOClient->emit('chat message', ['msg' => 'bar']);
    $elephantIOClient->close();

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

My server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

When i refresh my index page it return

> a user connected

But my "msg" data declared right here

> $elephantIOClient->emit('chat message', ['msg' => 'bar']);

Is not rendered or not passed to socket.io and it return

> a user connected
>
> message: [object Object]
>
> user disconnected

I already read topic with this problem but never for a php / elephant.io implementation.

Does somebody already had this problem or do you have some ideas too fix this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for late reply but landed here since I am working on socket.io and elephant.io in my project.
Anyways your connection is perfect and since your are logging an object in client side `console.log('message: ' + msg);` you are getting `[object Object]` as result. Try `.` operator to get the actual data.

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){  
   console.log('message: ' + msg.msg);
                               //^^^^-- here since you are sending your object as "msg" from server
}
```

Comment: Yea this is working well, but right now i'm using node.js only with js file without elephant.io and it is working like a charm but i don't know if it's the good way.